# AG Grid: How to stick the scrolling at bottom

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

i'm using AG Grid Angular to create a log view, i will add a lot of entries per second to the grid, typically this type of view's has the newest entry at the bottom, so it would be great if there is a good way where the scrolling will stick at the bottom, so i can always see the latest entry. A bonus would be, if i can manually scroll up and the scrolling will stay at this position.

Comment: See [ask], show us what you have tried so far. Go through how to create [mcve]. Share ur code on plunk or stackblitz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

handle `rowDataChanged` in your markup:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  class="ag-dark"
  [rowData]="messages"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  (bodyScroll)="handleScroll($event)"
  (rowDataChanged)="handleRowDataChanged($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

In the handler for `rowDataChanged`, call `ensureVisibleIndex` to scroll to the last row added:

```
  gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    suppressScrollOnNewData: true,
  }
  handleRowDataChanged(event) {
    const index = this.messages.length - 1;
    this.gridOptions.api.ensureIndexVisible(index, 'bottom');
  }
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-stuck-to-bottom

In that code there is also some logic around when to keep the table scrolled to the end or not based on the scroll position.